# How to correctly read many .txt files and store them in a user-defined structure in Fortran?

Tags: data-structures, fortran, read-data, user-defined-data-types

I often use an user-defined data type to read data from a .txt file and so that to store them in a structure. Now I've to face the problem to read many .txt files (i.e. 50) and each of them contains 200 rows. File names differ only by a number: 01,02,03,...and so on up to 50.

Here I report 3 out of 50 files (for simplicity) and always for simplicity I report only 10 out of 200 rows.

file no.1: "SEM_L1_uns_01_CI_Osc_Eleme"

```
 ind,               t_CI_rad,                   a_km,                      e,                ome_rad,                 ta_rad,
   1,  0.449495085019258E+01,  0.142794469595564E+09,  0.311319238356502E-01,  0.373317182819416E+01,  0.391600344732439E+01
   2,  0.449490417525976E+01,  0.142795969461762E+09,  0.311196378604465E-01,  0.373310687831689E+01,  0.391602540304241E+01
   3,  0.449486946238395E+01,  0.142797470883346E+09,  0.311072958572658E-01,  0.373304921821674E+01,  0.391605246892087E+01
   4,  0.449481221981096E+01,  0.142798990192101E+09,  0.310949071771324E-01,  0.373299338188810E+01,  0.391605469623775E+01
   5,  0.449479293487995E+01,  0.142800494644145E+09,  0.310824893928447E-01,  0.373294910339002E+01,  0.391608444326768E+01
   6,  0.449472679999995E+01,  0.142802026579605E+09,  0.310700474689325E-01,  0.373290284423826E+01,  0.391606817815260E+01
   7,  0.449470185723112E+01,  0.142803538990651E+09,  0.310576015308272E-01,  0.373286875105654E+01,  0.391608213476193E+01
   8,  0.449466025687995E+01,  0.142805060293773E+09,  0.310451588370723E-01,  0.373283758502234E+01,  0.391607615682697E+01
   9,  0.449461774159995E+01,  0.142806580857677E+09,  0.310327331435368E-01,  0.373281189771104E+01,  0.391606384901479E+01
```

file no.2: "SEM_L1_uns_02_CI_Osc_Eleme"

```
 ind,               t_CI_rad,                   a_km,                      e,                ome_rad,                 ta_rad,
   1,  0.449593968023960E+01,  0.142764774644796E+09,  0.314820846352711E-01,  0.370440771605004E+01,  0.394445865556203E+01
   2,  0.449565715032919E+01,  0.142777831570809E+09,  0.313758271713642E-01,  0.370382849782126E+01,  0.394478884474319E+01
   3,  0.449539999999995E+01,  0.142790893388701E+09,  0.312693284046952E-01,  0.370329289450031E+01,  0.394510263682302E+01
   4,  0.449512068023960E+01,  0.142803968920708E+09,  0.311627131383232E-01,  0.370279429271386E+01,  0.394535773596877E+01
   5,  0.449486946238395E+01,  0.142817021215803E+09,  0.310560704116879E-01,  0.370234103760294E+01,  0.394559742741739E+01
   6,  0.449461774159995E+01,  0.142830050607520E+09,  0.309495163003550E-01,  0.370192936392300E+01,  0.394579603457124E+01
   7,  0.449437953523112E+01,  0.142843037532608E+09,  0.308431510464130E-01,  0.370156205104728E+01,  0.394596514326382E+01
   8,  0.449413912199995E+01,  0.142855976756040E+09,  0.307370836364728E-01,  0.370123724668890E+01,  0.394609040220335E+01
   9,  0.449392020904272E+01,  0.142868844485990E+09,  0.306314091902416E-01,  0.370095923694675E+01,  0.394619184787349E+01
```

file no.3: "SEM_L1_uns_03_CI_Osc_Eleme"

```
 ind,               t_CI_rad,                   a_km,                      e,                ome_rad,                 ta_rad,
   1,  0.450530851546761E+01,  0.142777546066889E+09,  0.314859242864061E-01,  0.369875801989520E+01,  0.395891682081399E+01
   2,  0.450498923999995E+01,  0.142796089006232E+09,  0.313353834423384E-01,  0.369794633559255E+01,  0.395945835455125E+01
   3,  0.450470185723112E+01,  0.142814597099893E+09,  0.311847556982832E-01,  0.369719153846116E+01,  0.395997746151854E+01
   4,  0.450441446238395E+01,  0.142833065102397E+09,  0.310342127667357E-01,  0.369648984636881E+01,  0.396044506280060E+01
   5,  0.450412599999995E+01,  0.142851474488369E+09,  0.308839062523069E-01,  0.369584205674238E+01,  0.396085922026455E+01
   6,  0.450384427882598E+01,  0.142869803179719E+09,  0.307339805170313E-01,  0.369525032447206E+01,  0.396122575198223E+01
   7,  0.450355580715757E+01,  0.142888039303578E+09,  0.305845883394130E-01,  0.369471354832856E+01,  0.396153182323339E+01
   8,  0.450330089329288E+01,  0.142906146829379E+09,  0.304358523798026E-01,  0.369423894192417E+01,  0.396181161339849E+01
   9,  0.450303719679291E+01,  0.142924128161207E+09,  0.302879342780738E-01,  0.369382093401531E+01,  0.396202708268508E+01
```

Here is my main program:

```
 program Main_Ast_ManifoldTraj
    
    use DataType
    use DataHandling

    implicit none

       ! Declarations  
    character*100 :: input_path_ast,input_path_SEM_L1_uns,input_path_SEM_L2_uns,input_filename_ast, output_path
    character*2   :: str_Jacobi_cst
    type(Asteroid)     , dimension (:), allocatable :: Ast_data
    type(Inv_manifold) , dimension (:,:), allocatable :: Inv_manif_data
    integer   :: iu_in_ast,iu_in_invManif,no_ast_orb,no_L_points,no_Jacobi_cst,no_invManif_orb,iu_out,n_lines_InvManif,n_lines_ast,ierr,n_omega,i,nSol,nSol_test,iCase
    integer,  dimension (50) :: iu_in_L1_orb, iu_in_L2_orb
    real(pr)  :: xmu,a1,a2,e1,e2
    real(pr)  :: p1,p2,rpi1,rpi2,ral1,ral2
    real(pr)  :: tau1,tau2,delta,domega,th1,th2,th1_test,th2_test,omega1,omega2,domega_test,RAAN1,RAAN2, ang1_IRF,ang2_IRF
    real(pr)  :: xi1,xi2,yi1,yi2,dv1,dv2,xi1_test,xi2_test,yi1_test,yi2_test,xi1_IRF,xi2_IRF,yi1_IRF,yi2_IRF
    real(pr)  :: cos_ang1_IRF, sin_ang1_IRF
    
    

    ! Definition of constants, paths names and file names
    iu_in_ast       = 10 ! unit number relative to asteroid file
    
    ! Generate an equally space 1D array about the unit number from 1 to 50 to correctly read input files about L1-orbits
    call linspace(from=1, to=50, array = iu_in_L1_orb)  
    ! Generate an equally space 1D array about the unit number from 1 to 50 to correctly read input files about L2-orbits
    call linspace(from=1, to=50, array = iu_in_L2_orb)  
   
    iu_out          = 12

    input_path_ast        = 'D:\OneDrive\MSc_Thesis\Projects\Ast_InvManifoldTraj_Intersect_ellipses_DV\InputFiles\'
    input_path_SEM_L1_uns = 'D:\OneDrive\MSc_Thesis\Projects\Ast_InvManifoldTraj_Intersect_ellipses_DV\InputFiles\SEM_L1_uns\'
    input_path_SEM_L2_uns = 'D:\OneDrive\MSc_Thesis\Projects\Ast_InvManifoldTraj_Intersect_ellipses_DV\InputFiles\SEM_L2_uns\'
    
    input_filename_ast = 'Ast_data.csv'
    
    output_path =  'D:\OneDrive\MSc_Thesis\Projects\Intersect_ellipses_DV_computation\OutputFiles\'
    !output_filename = 'inters_DV_EM_ast'//no_ast//'.csv'
    !output_filename_test = 'inters_EM_ast'//trim(no_ast)//'.csv'
    !
    ! Definition of number of asteroids orbits, L-points, Jacobi constants and invariant manifold orbits
    no_ast_orb      = 50  ! 50 asteroids
    no_L_points     = 2   ! 2 L-points (L1, L2)
    no_Jacobi_cst   = 50  ! 50 values of Jacobi constant for each L-point
    no_invManif_orb = 200 ! 200 orbits for each Jacobi constant
        
    !! Import asteroid data by using "read_ast_data" subroutine
    call read_ast_data(iu_in_ast, input_path_ast, input_filename_ast, n_lines_ast, Ast_data) ! distances in km, angles in deg
    
    !! Import invariant manifold trajectories relative to L1
    ! Convert integer number to a string in order to correctly read the files (write in the string "no_Jacobi_cst" the integer number "i_Jacobi_cst")
    do i = 1, no_Jacobi_cst
        if (i .lt. 10) then
                write(str_Jacobi_cst,'(i2.2)') i ! an integer of width 2 with zeros at the left
            else
                write(str_Jacobi_cst,'(i2)')   i
        endif
        call read_invManif_data(iu_in_L1_orb(i), input_path_SEM_L1_uns, 'SEM_L1_uns_'//str_Jacobi_cst//'_CI_Osc_Eleme.txt',no_Jacobi_cst, n_lines_InvManif, Inv_manif_data(:,i))  !this is line 74
    
end program Main_Ast_ManifoldTraj
```

Here are my modules:

```
module DataType

    implicit none

    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: pr = SELECTED_REAL_KIND (p = 15) 

    !"Asteroid_data" data type declaration 
    type  Asteroid                           
        integer(pr) :: index                 
        character*10 :: pdes                       
        real(pr) :: epoch            
        real(pr) :: a   
        real(pr) :: e 
        real(pr) :: i 
        real(pr) :: om 
        real(pr) :: w 
        real(pr) :: ta
        real(pr) :: ang_pos_IRF
    end type Asteroid 
    
    !"Inv_manifold_traj" data type declaration 
    type  Inv_manifold                          
        integer(pr) :: index                                                 
        real(pr) :: time_CI  
        real(pr) :: a
        real(pr) :: e 
        real(pr) :: w 
        real(pr) :: ta                       
    end type Inv_manifold  
    
end module DataType

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

module DataHandling
    
    use DataType
    
    implicit none
    
    contains 

    !***********************************************************************
    subroutine read_ast_data(UnitNum, FilePath, FileName, LinesNum, Ast_data)
    !***********************************************************************
    ! Subroutine for reading of asteroids database 
    !***********************************************************************
    !  INPUT:

    !
    !  OUTPUT:

    !***********************************************************************
        implicit none
    
        ! Arguments
        integer, intent (in) :: UnitNum
        character (len=*), intent (in) :: FilePath
        character (len=*), intent (in) :: FileName
        integer, intent (out) :: LinesNum
        type(Asteroid), dimension (:), allocatable, intent(out) :: Ast_data
      
        !Local variables
        integer :: i, iflag

        open(unit = UnitNum, file = trim(FilePath) // trim(FileName), status='old', & 
                access = 'sequential',form = 'formatted', action='read')
    
            ! Count lines 
            LinesNum = 0
            read(UnitNum,*)  ! Skip first line (containing variable names)
            do     
                read(UnitNum,*,iostat = iflag)
                if (iflag/=0) exit
                LinesNum =  LinesNum + 1
            enddo
         
            rewind(UnitNum)
    
            ! Variables allocation
            allocate(Ast_data(LinesNum))
        
            ! Data reading 
            read(UnitNum,'(a)')  ! skip header line (variables names will be assigned again)
            do i = 1, LinesNum
                read(UnitNum,*) Ast_data(i)         
            enddo
        
        close(unit = UnitNum, status='keep') 
        
        return

    end subroutine read_ast_data

    !***********************************************************************
    subroutine read_invManif_data(UnitNum, FilePath, FileName,no_Jac_cst, LinesNum, InvManif_data)
    !***********************************************************************
    ! Subroutine for reading of Earth ephemerides at four reference epochs of asteroids
    !***********************************************************************
    !  INPUT:

    !
    !  OUTPUT:

    !***********************************************************************
        implicit none
    
        ! Arguments
        integer, intent (in) :: UnitNum
        character (len=*), intent (in) :: FilePath
        character (len=*), intent (in) :: FileName
        integer, intent (in)    :: no_Jac_cst
        integer, intent (out) :: LinesNum
        type(Inv_manifold), dimension (:,:), allocatable, intent(out) :: InvManif_data
        
        !Local variables
        integer :: i, iflag

        open(unit = UnitNum, file = trim(FilePath) // trim(FileName), status='old', & 
                access = 'sequential',form = 'formatted', action='read')
    
            ! Count lines 
            LinesNum = 0
            read(UnitNum,*)  ! Skip first line (containing variable names)
            do     
                read(UnitNum,*,iostat = iflag)
                if (iflag/=0) exit
                LinesNum =  LinesNum + 1
            enddo
         
            rewind(UnitNum)
    
            ! Variables allocation
            allocate(InvManif_data(LinesNum,no_Jac_cst))
        
            ! Data reading 
            read(UnitNum,'(a)')  ! skip header line (variables names will be assigned again)
            do i = 1, LinesNum
                read(UnitNum,*) InvManif_data(i,:)         
            enddo
        
        close(unit = UnitNum, status='keep') 
        
        return

    end subroutine read_invManif_data
    !*********************************************************************** 
    
    !***********************************************************************
    subroutine linspace(from, to, array)
    !***********************************************************************
    ! Generates evenly spaced numbers from `from` to `to` (inclusive).
    !
    ! Inputs:
    ! -------
    !
    ! from, to : the lower and upper boundaries of the numbers to generate
    !
    ! Outputs:
    ! -------
    !
    ! array : Array of evenly spaced numbers
    !***********************************************************************
        implicit none
    
        !Arguments
        integer, intent(in)  :: from, to
        integer, intent(out) :: array(:)
        
        real(pr) :: range
        integer :: n, i
    
        n = size(array)
        range = to - from

        if (n == 0) return

        if (n == 1) then
            array(1) = from
            return
        end if


        do i=1, n
            array(i) = from + range * (i - 1) / (n - 1)
        end do
        
        return
        
    end subroutine linspace
    !*********************************************************************** 
    
end module DataHandling
```

I realize that my structure has to be 2-dimensional but I get the following error when I perform debug of my program:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       error #6911: The syntax of this substring is invalid.   [INV_MANIF_DATA]        line-74
```

Can you help me to correctly import all data of all files?

Comment: Isn't the error message **If dummy arg is allocatable, actual arg must be a whole array and not a section.** quite clear? If your subroutine or function argument is allocatable, you can only pass allocatable stuff to that subroutine/function. And a subarray (array section) is never allocatable.

Comment: The error message speaks about line 74 and about `Inv_manif_data(:,i)`. I suppose that  line 74 is probably `call read_invManif_data(iu_in_L1_orb(i), input_path_SEM_L1_uns, 'SEM_L1_uns_'//str_Jacobi_cst//'_CI_Osc_Eleme.txt', n_lines_InvManif, Inv_manif_data(:,i))` and that the last arg of `read_invManif_data` is `allocatable`. **Does it really need to be `allocatable`?**

Comment: The duplicate I linked basically repeats in general what I mentioned in the two previous comments. The key is: Doe the `read_invManif_data` *really* need an allocatable dummy argument?

Comment: Hi @VladimirFГероямслава and sorry for my previus question, I missed a module and now I get a different error...The allocation that I used for the arg `Inv_manif_data` reflects the same procedure I've used for `Ast_data` in the previous commented call.

Comment: The error I explained in my first two comments and which the duplicate link links to is still there. Perhaps you now have another error but you did nothing with the original error.

Comment: In `subroutine read_invManif_data(UnitNum, FilePath, FileName,no_Jac_cst, LinesNum, InvManif_data)` the last argument is `allocatable`. You simply cannot pass there anything like `Inv_manif_data(:,i)`, whatever `nv_manif_data` happens to be, because **a subarray (array section) is never allocatable** even if it is a subarray of an allocatable array.

Comment: Be aware that your loop `do i = 1, no_Jacobi_cst` is unterminated.

Comment: Regarding your current code, I cannot reproduce your new error message. If add the missing `end do`, I get the old error message `If dummy arg is allocatable, actual arg must be a whole array and not a section.` and also `The shape matching rules of actual arguments and dummy arguments have been violated.` because the subarray is 1D and not 2D.